# Issues with global variables and their values

Tags: python, loops, variables

I'm having some issues with this code. There is a lot of other code to go with it but none that will interfere or have any affect on the issue I'm having. So basically, when I run the code and we get to the for loop at the bottom, it prints nothing because apparently the variable 'walls' = 0, even though I've already given it a valid input. If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

```
global walls
global wallLengths
walls = 0
wall = 0
wallLengths = 0

def clientDetails():
    #global walls

    print("Welcome to the InHouse Solutions Room Painting Price Calculator")

    print("STEP 1 - CLIENT DETAILS")
    print("Please enter your full name")
    userName = input(">>>")

    print("Please enter your post code")
    postCode = input(">>>")

    print("Please enter you first address line here:")
    addressLineOne = input(">>>")

    print("Please enter your second address line here (OPTIONAL)")
    addressLineTwo = input(">>>")


    print("Thank you for your information")
    print (userName)
    print (addressLineOne + ", " + addressLineTwo + ", " + postCode)
    print (" ")

    def ValidationOne():
        print ("Is this information correct? Pleast enter Yes or No")
        clientDetailsCorrect = input(">>>")

        if clientDetailsCorrect == "no" or clientDetailsCorrect == "No":
            clientDetails()
        elif clientDetailsCorrect == "Yes" or clientDetailsCorrect == "yes":
            roomDimensions()
        else:
            ("Invalid response, please try again")
            ValidationOne()

    ValidationOne()      

def roomDimensions():
    global walls 
    print ("STEP 2 - ROOM DIMENSIONS")

    def ValidationTwo():
        global walls
        print ("How many walls does your room have?")
        walls = int(input(">>>"))
        if walls > 10 or walls < 3:
            print("Invalid, please enter a number between 3 and 10")
            ValidationTwo()
        elif walls == " " or walls == "":
            print("Invalid")
            ValidationTwo()

    def ValidationThree():
        global walls
        print ("How tall is the room in meters?")
        roomHeight = float(input(">>>"))
        if roomHeight < 2.4 or roomHeight > 6:
            print ("Invalid, please enter a value between 2.4 and 6")
            ValidationThree()

    def IndividualWalls():
        global wallLengths
        global walls
        for i in range(1,walls):
            print("Please enter the width of wall" , i)
            wallLengths[i] = float(input(">>>"))

    ValidationTwo()
    ValidationThree()
    IndividualWalls()
clientDetails()
```

Comment: What happens if you change `#global walls` to `global walls`?

Comment: Nothing, it's just the global variable, it's having no trouble delivering the variable between functions but instead struggling to hold the value i give it. I think it's something to do with converting it between string and integers, not sure though.

Comment: What if you use global walls here `walls = int(input(">>>"))`

Comment: I've moved global walls around and now it is managing to hold the value for walls, but it can't make it past the first input in the for loop. The error message is: "TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment"

Comment: Well, seems like `wallLength` is an `int`, and not a `list`. Please post all the relevant code.

Comment: I've now updated the original code above.

Comment: Where is `wallLengths` initialized?

Comment: Only in the for loop at the end, otherwise it is only declared global at the top of the code.

Comment: The problem is that you set `wallLengths` to `0` (an int), yet try to use it like a list.

Comment: The other problem is the usage of global variables at all ...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know how to fix this. Anyone provide me with an example?

Comment: Well I've changed everything that you've all suggested and have gotten nowhere, you've all been thoroughly useless, thank you all for nothing.

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to use 'global' keyword when declaring a global at the top of the script:

```python
>>> walls = 0
>>> def increase_walls():
...   global walls
...   walls += 1
...   print walls
... 
>>> increase_walls()
1
```

Comment: Thank you, but that doesn't really fix my issue.

Answer (score -1):

I can't comment to your question because I don't have over 50 reputation so I will ask here
Can you tell me what the function roomDimensions does? 
I tried to run it and you have some deep recursion problem (you can't call recursion function without any if - it will run forever) BUT the first thing that I notice is that you don’t initialize the walls variable so it will not be global variable it will be non-local variable. and you  don't call any inner function ( ValidationTwo, ValidationThree,IndividualWalls)

so you main problems are: (handle them in this order)

1. walls initialize
2. you didn't call any inner function
3. deep recursion

here is my example for the use of the three of above:

```
global_var = 12

def outer():
    global global_var
    print("*"*10)
    print('hello im outer function')
    print("*"*10)
    def inner1():
        global global_var
        print('hello im inner1 function')
        if global_var < 10:
            return 'end for inner1' 
        print ('global_var is: ' + str(global_var))
        global_var -= 1
        return inner1()

    def inner2():
        global global_var
        print('hello im inner2 function')
        if global_var >= 10:
            return 'end for inner1' 
        print ('global_var is: ' + str(global_var))
        global_var += 1
        return inner2()

    if global_var >= 10:
        return inner1()
    else:
        return inner2()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print outer()
```

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that you have walls initialize and you call the inner function...
but you don't need you declare walls as global in the initialize because you are already in the global environment